# (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x80010105 (RPC_E_SERVERFAULT)) почему возникает и как с ним бороться

Tags: c#, com

При разработке использую COM библиотеку. Иногда (закономерности мне так и не удалось выявить, подозреваю что из-за слишком частых обращений к СOM библиотеке) при доступе к COM объекту или вызова метода выходит следующая ошибка:

```
Ошибка на сервере. (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x80010105 (RPC_E_SERVERFAULT))
```

К сожалению, гугление мне не смогло дать ответа почему происходит эта ошибка и что она означает или хотя бы как ее избежать. Хотелось бы узнать может есть статья в которой описывались подобные ошибки более подробно т.е. хотя бы причину их возникновения.

Comment: так же если после возникновения ошибки попытаться обратиться к  COM DLL то возникает следующая ошибка:
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800706BA): Сервер RPC недоступен. (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x800706BA)

Comment: К библиотеке идет обращение из одного потока, или разных?

Comment: Из одного потока

Comment: Тогда тут вам ничем не помогут. Это специфика работы конкретной библиотеки. Попробуйте связаться с разработчиками